# Wordpress prepared LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to use a prepared `LIKE` query within Wordpress, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've followed the codex for the syntax.

```
public function userByJobId($id){        
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM use_users WHERE use_job_id LIKE = d%;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like((int)$id)) . '%');

    if(!empty($result)){
       return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling the method like so:

```
$userid = 1
$user = new Users();
$user_id = $user->userByJobId($userid);
```

Cant see where the issue lies..

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Well after the query, i tried to print the result if its not empty (which it wont be if the query is correct) but nothing :(

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders

Comment: Not sure how wordpress handles queries but "LIKE =" is no valid SQL either use LIKE or "=" but not both.

Answer (score 2):

The [wordpress class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) tells me that:

> Possible format values: %s as string; %d as integer (whole number);
>   and %f as float.

When you want to prepare a query with a like comparison you should [double escape percentages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67292/how-to-use-wildcards-in-wpdb-queries-using-wpdb-get-results-wpdb-prepare).

So change

`$result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM use_users WHERE use_job_id LIKE = d%;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like((int)$id)) . '%');`

To

`$result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM use_users WHERE use_job_id LIKE %%%d%%;",(int)$id));`

You also don't have to escape values (the prepare method does that for you).

**Warning: Non tested code**

Comment: This is a wrong LIKE syntax. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A few points have been made already:

- Syntax for `prepare()` is the same as that for `sprintf`; a decimal placeholder is `%d`, not `d%`
- The `LIKE` keyword shouldn't be followed by an equals, just the expression to test against

A few other things:

- You concatenate the `LIKE` `%` wildcard after the closing parenthesis for `prepare()`, where it should be concatenated before
- `get_row()` will return an object by default, not just the ID, which is a property of the object returned

```
public function userByJobId($id){        
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}job_id LIKE %d;",
            '%' . $wpdb->esc_like((int)$id)  . '%'
        )
    );

    if($result){
       return $result->ID;
    }
    return false;
}
```